# ModuleNotFoundError (customtkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, customtkinter

I have a problem when using the library `customtkinter`. An error message appears stating that the library does not exist even though I downloaded the library using `pip`. I also checked the library path and found it with the rest of the libraries that I downloaded previously.

I imported the library and wrote a simple code to make sure it worked, and I received the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\VS code\Python\ggg.py", line 1, in <module>
    import customtkinter as ctk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customtkinter'
```

The code I wrote was as follows:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
root = ctk.CTk()
root.mainloop()
```

Note: I am using Python version 3.11.4, and I downloaded the latest version of the library, which is 5.2.1.

What's wrong?

Comment: The usual cause of this is that VSCode has its own installation of Python, and you installed your module in the wrong one.

Comment: `tkinter` comes with python.  so no installation is required....